# AutoPostBack on CheckBox control sometimes fails

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, postback, autopostback

If have the below markup.

```
<asp:checkbox id="chkTVLic" runat="server" text="TV Licence" oncheckedchanged="chkDocs_CheckChanged"
                                autopostback="true" CausesValidation="false" />
                            <asp:panel id="pnlTVLic" runat="server" visible="false">
                                <div class="toggle-item-link1 document-date">
                                    <asp:panel id="pnlTVLicIssueDate" runat="server">
                                        <p>
                                            Please enter the date of issue
                                        </p>
                                        <div class="fm-req">
                                            <asp:textbox id="txtTVLicIssueDate" cssclass="tb size2" runat="server" onblur="return true;"></asp:textbox>
                                            <cc2:calendarextender id="caleTVLicIssueDate" runat="server" targetcontrolid="txtTVLicIssueDate"
                                                popupbuttonid="ibnTVLicIssueDate" popupposition="BottomLeft" animated="true"
                                                format="dd/MM/yyyy">
                                            </cc2:calendarextender>
                                            <asp:imagebutton id="ibnTVLicIssueDate" runat="server" imageurl="../images/img-calendar-day.png"
                                                alternatetext="Calendar" tooltip="Pick Date" cssclass="date-picker" />
                                            <asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="rfvTVLicIssueDate" CssClass="error" runat="server" controltovalidate="txtTVLicIssueDate"
                                                display="Dynamic" errormessage="Required" setfocusonerror="true" validationgroup="TVLic"></asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
                                            <asp:comparevalidator id="cmvTVLicIssueDate" CssClass="error" runat="server" errormessage="Not a valid date"
                                                controltovalidate="txtTVLicIssueDate" operator="DataTypeCheck" type="Date" setfocusonerror="true"
                                                validationgroup="TVLic" display="Dynamic" cultureinvariantvalues="true"></asp:comparevalidator>
                                            <asp:customvalidator id="cuvTVLicIssueDate12Months" CssClass="error" runat="server" controltovalidate="txtTVLicIssueDate"
                                                validationgroup="TVLic" display="Dynamic" onservervalidate="cuvDocIssueDate12Months_ServerValidate"
                                                errormessage="Document must be less than 12 months old."></asp:customvalidator>
                                        </div>
                                    </asp:panel>
                                    <asp:panel id="pnlTVLicApprove" runat="server">
                                        <asp:LinkButton id="lbnTVLicApprove" runat="server" CssClass="screen-hide"
                                                alternatetext="Confirm TV Licence" tooltip="Confirm TV Licence" Text="OK" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="lbnApproveConfirm_Click"  />

                                        <asp:imagebutton id="ibnTVLicApprove" runat="server" imageurl="../images/img-accept-doc-off.png"
                                            alternatetext="Approve" tooltip="Approve" cssclass="approval-btn" causesvalidation="true" validationgroup="TVLic" OnMouseDown="HandleApproveClick('TVLic','lbnTVLicApprove');return false;" OnClientClick="HandleApproveClick('TVLic','lbnTVLicApprove');return false;" />
                                        <span class="approval-label">Accept document:</span></asp:panel>
                                </div>
                            </asp:panel>
```

The app is written in c# but i havn't posted any actual code as all the user code related to this markup seems to work fine.

The problem is the CheckBox chkTVLic has causes validation set to false and autopostback set to true.  So whatever happens when i check and uncheck the checkbox it should postback.  Most of the time this is exactly what it does and the result is to show and hide pnlTVLic when it is checked and unchecked.  However if any on the validators within the panel fire, the checkbox does not cause a postback the first time.  It will on all subsequent times but never the first.  However it should ALWAYS cause a postback.  What could be stopping it.  Before someone asks there is no use written client side code, everything is pure .net markup and c# code.

Comment: Why should the CheckBox cause a postback at all, when a validator fires? It will do a postback whenever the user clicks on it, AFAIK.

Comment: This is a very old post but my point was not that a checkbox should postback when a validator fires. It was that that it should do a postback whenever a user clicks on it irrespective of the validation state of other controls. However the behavior is was experiencing was that it worked fine if none of the validators had fired and posted back as expected, however if any of the validators had fired you had to click it twice to get it to post back.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why it shouldn't postback when you `check/uncheck` the `checkbox`, but if the only purpose of that checkbox is to `hide/unhide` a panel, I would rather do it in javascript. Doing a full postback to the server just for hiding some panel seems really bad.

In javascript you can do this to hide the panel:

```
document.getElementById('<%=pnlTVLic.ClientID%>').display='none';
```

And this to show it:

```
document.getElementById('<%=pnlTVLic.ClientID%>').display='block';
```

It's going to be so much faster and better. Just put a regular checkbox instead of the ASP.NET one and subscribe to the onclick event.

---

Sorry, one more comment:

I think you are wrong when you say that the checkbox should ALWAYS cause a postback. No, if one of the validators fires inside the panel, the checkbox will not cause a postback until the condition is satisfied.

Comment: NO it should not, it has causevalidation set to false, it should ignore all validators and post back regardless.  Which is what it does, 2 and all other times.  I know how to show and hide a div in javascript, the reason it causes a post back becuase there is other server side processing that needs to take place.  So long as the checkbox posts back everything id dandy.

Comment: Benn, you are right. I googled a bit and it appears that this is a known issue. How about doing the whole thing from javascript any way? I mean, hide/unhide the panel and then simply do a form.submit?

Comment: Yeah it's for about 40 checkboxes lots of work recoding in JS.

Comment: If all of them do the same thing; it should only be one simple js function and not 40. I don't know, i'm just throwing some ideas.

Comment: you are wrong here. that checkbox should be independent from validators in that panel if its tagged: CausesValidation="false".
Same problem for me, when i submit form and some validations are fired, i press on checkbox - FIRST time never postback is fired because of those validators. And its WRONG, because i i added tag that is should not causevalidation.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and it worked.
on checkbox onclick event I disabled all the `validation` controls and immediately did `Page_ClientValidate();` and it worked.